# Как получить id пользователя запустившого процесс в freeBSD

Tags: freebsd

В Linux вроде есть файл /proc/stat. А в freeBSD я этот файл найти не могу. Есть только status

Comment: http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?procstat

Comment: Это через вызов. А мне нужна функция. Хотя я уже нашел способ найти id user и через /proc/status и через https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?sysctl(3)